# magento 2 getting product data from wishlist

Tags: magento2, wishlist

Coming in to trouble while getting correct data from my wishlist:

```
/** 
    @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $_wishlist 
    @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $_customerSession
*/
$wishlistCollection = $this->_wishlist->loadByCustomerId($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId(), true)->getItemCollection();
foreach($wishlistCollection as $wishedItem){
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product; */
    $product = $this->_product->setStoreId($wishedItem->getStoreId())->load($wishedItem->getProductId);
    /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Rating $_rating; */
    $rating = $this->_rating->getEntitySummary($wishedItem->getProductId(), true);
    $ratingValue = NULL;
    if($rating->getSum() && $rating->getCount()) $ratingValue = $rating->getSum()/$rating->getCount();

    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getSku();
    echo $product->getProductUrl();
    echo $ratingValue;
}
```

product 1 was clone of the original product. Product 1 has rating while original has no reviews.Review to product 1 was added after dublicating.

while in the loop product name and sku are different, but url and rating values are the same, so not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to load products reuses the same product model. 
In that way you will have data of the previous product in cases in which the new product for example does not a have data for a specific attribute.

You should use a product factory instead for loading the product in the following way:

```
protected $_productFactory;

//inject product factory in constructor
public function __construct(
    [...]
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
   {
       [...]
       $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
   }

   [...]
   //load product
   $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->setStoreId($wishedItem->getStoreId())->load($wishedItem->getProductId);
```

Or at least call `reset()` on your product model before loading a new product:

```
   $product = $this->_product->reset()->setStoreId($wishedItem->getStoreId())->load($wishedItem->getProductId);
```

Comment: Thanks, now only rating problem remains. Even with reset it shows same values.

Comment: try the same approach and use a factory insetad of the rate model:  `$rating = $this->_ratingFactory->create();` and inject `\Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory`

Comment: thx, reset was working too but problem was with cache..